# example of compact manifold with $K\le 0$

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Could you give an example of such Riemannian manifold: 1. compact; 2. non-positive sectional curvature

Answer (score 3):

The usual example is a "flat torus": $[0,1]^2$ with the top and bottom, as well as left and right, edges identified.

There are similar examples with constant negative curvature, but they are a bit more involved to describe.

One possibility is to take two regular hyperbolic right-angled octagons and glue them together along opposite edges, producing a cylinder-like thing with two longitudinal seams where each end has four right-angled corners. You can then glue each of these edges shut by identifying parts of them in the flat-torus pattern.

```
      B--3--C              Q--3--R
     /       \            /       \
    4         4          5         5
   /           \        /           \
  A             D      P             S
  |             |      |             |
  1             2      2             1
  |             |      |             |
  H             E      W             T
   \           /        \           /
    7         7          8         8
     \       /            \       /
      G--6--F              V--6--U
```

The resulting manifold is a genus-2 surface. It has four points where four of the original octagon corners come together:

```
    |           |           |           |
    5           2           1           8
   Q|R         P|D         T|H         U|V
-3--+--3-   -5--+--4-   -8--+--7-   -6--+--6-
   C|B         S|A         W|E         G|F
    4           1           2           7
    |           |           |           |
```

---

A **simpler construction** would be to take a larger hyperbolic octagon with corner angle 45°, and simply identify opposite sides (preserving orientation). This also produces a compact genus-2 surface with constant negative curvature.

Comment: The flat torus can also be realized as $S^1 \times S^1 \subset \mathbb R^4$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_torus.

Comment: oh I didn't notice this usual example, my original intention is to find a manifold with $K<0$

Comment: @user360777: I've described one hyperbolic example (not particularly distinguished except the first orientable one I could come up with).

Comment: @HenningMakholm i don't totally understand it, is this topologically 2-torus or Klein bottle?

Comment: @user360777: There result is homeomorphic to a [double torus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleTorus.html). Once you have glued sides 1-1 and 2-2 together, what you have is homeomorphic to two rectangles (BCQR) and (GFVU) connected by a handle, and then you stitch each of those rectangles into a torus.

Comment: There are several other possible ways to stitch the two octagons together that also produce genus-2 surfaces (including ones that are not globally isometric to this one, unless I'm much mistaken).

Comment: @HenningMakholm [Preissman's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preissman%27s_theorem) says if M is a compact Riemannian manifold with $K<0$, the any nontrivial Abelian subgroup of $\pi_1(M)$ is infinite cyclic, so a 2-torus cannot carry such a metric. I think this glued manifold is unbound as a complete manifold then non-compact.

Comment: @user360777: The theorem you reference excludes a _2-dimensional torus_ (a 2D surface of genus 1), which is something different from the _double torus_ (a 2D surface of genus 2) that results here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm it's not 2-dimensional torus, the fundamental group of double torus is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ but it's not infinite cyclic

Comment: @user360777: $\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$ is the fundamental group for a 2-dimensional torus, **but not of the double torus**.

Comment: Also, it is impossible to get a non-compact surface by stitching together a finite number of compact patches -- that produces a quotient space, and all quotients of a compact space are compact.

Comment: @HenningMakholm fundamental group is a topological invariant, so it's not about the dimension of Euclidean space the tori is embedded (like 3 or 4), but only the genus of the 2-dimensional orientable closed manifold

Comment: @user360777: I'm not talking about "the dimension of the Euclidean space the tori is embedded in". A double torus **is not homeomorphic** to an ordinary 2-dimensional torus. It has different genus (2 rather than 1), and a different fundamental group!

Comment: @HenningMakholm i think i got something wrong, you're right! one more question, how you deal with the boundary when gluing? i mean the octagon doesn't have a boundary

Comment: @user360777: Why would the octagon not have a bounday?

Comment: @HenningMakholm you can't define a metric on the boundary

Comment: @user360777: Umm, how is that different from the usual stitching construction for the flat torus? To be completely formal, I think you could have a chart for each of the octagon interiors, a chart for each of the four shared corners, and a long thin chart for each of the eight seams.

Comment: @HenningMakholm here you need to consider the metric, you can't define a metric on the boundary, like the Poincare's hyperbolic disk, the boundary is 'infinity'. when dealing with just topology, you don't have to consider this

Comment: @user360777: The octagon is finite: a bounded, closed subset of the hyperbolic plane. In the disk model it does not go near the boundary of the model.

Comment: @HenningMakholm i got it, thanks! it seems we can construct such a torus by gluing 2 squares similarly?

Comment: it seems the metric at the gluing boundary is continuous but not differentiable

Answer (score 2):

Take the unit disc $D$ in $\Bbb C$ with hyperbolic metric, then factor it by a discrete group of Mobius transformations acting freely on $D$. If this group has the property that the quotient is compact, then you have an example.
(All compact Riemann surfaces of genus $\ge2$ can be obtained this way.)

Comment: But that doesn't tell us whether any such discrete group with compact quotient exists or not.

Comment: No, but by the Uniformisation Theorem for Riemann surfaces, there are plenty of them!